# merging code behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms

I am trying to merge some code behind code for .net that I found with the original code.  Ultimatley, I am trying to create a form that allows file attachments.  Everything I do produces an error and I can't find a site that identifies my problem.  Here is the code for the form...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>
```

And here is the code behind.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I merge these onto one page?

Comment: Include the full text of the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of the file, add this...

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
 <script runat="server">
 [code goes here]
 </script>
 <html>
 [page continues here]
```

I personally wouldn't advise having code and markup on the same page - I think they should be in separate files